# Fitting the ratio of skew normal distributions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, approximation, ratio

I have two probality functions that are following a skew normal distribution. I  compute the ratio between these functions. 
Can I approximate this ratio with a skew normal distribution also? Do you have any references where I can find a proper justification?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Even for independent $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$, the density function of $\dfrac XY$ has no closed form and is far from being that of a skew normal distribution.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco we might want to restrict the hypothesis to the case where the coefficient of variation is small enough, so that both X and Y would be positive only (or negative only) and *not so close* to zero...

Comment: @agenis That doesn't change it a lot since $\dfrac{cX}{cY}=\dfrac XY$ for any constant $c≠0$, i.e. up to scaling.

Comment: well, for instance in this paper it does provides approximations based on some condition on the location parameters (in the gaussian case only) https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v016i04/v16i04.pdf